# Expanding Possible Entities

Tags: database-design

I'm working on a personal project problem.  It's a donation management model.  I need to link donations to entities.  For example, the original set of entities that donate are Families, Companies, and Individuals.  I want to link donations to these entities and interrelate entities to each other.  Is there an example of designing this model where entities could expand and relationships don't get impacted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is self-explanatory.

[image: donation_model_v1]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an entity for donations, contacts, types in the least.  A basic idea:

```
types { id, TypeName } for families, companies, individuals
contacts { id, first name, last name , typeid, add1, addr2 .....}
donations { id, contactID, amount, other fields....}
```

Comment: what happens when 'types' expands.  I need something loosely coupled

Comment: If there is a new classification of type, you merely add a new record to the Types table.  So lets say a Civic organization like an Alumni Association.  You would then have Family, Business, Individual and Alumni Association in the Types table.

Answer (score 0):

You could always store the data in one table as structures and then have lookup tables for metadata, like the last time a donor was contacted, and add new data structures at will
[image]

Comment: If you change your mind, take a look at Android's source code. This is how the address book is built but with some additional columns